# How to make an Excel generated using Jasper as Readonly

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

There is an export to excel button
On click of that I want to generate a read only excel.I am using Jasper for generating Excel.
Is there any property which can be set to generate readonly excel

Answer (score 0):

you can use the net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.password property in the jrxml and make it protected. the value will be the password